# Licence for Bootstrap to use it in a project

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a social network and planning to use Bootsrap in the design, so I don't konw if it's legal or not , and if it's legal should I make something ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twitter Bootstrap uses the MIT license, so yes, you can use the library without any concerns.

See also the corresponding license file: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/LICENSE

Answer (score 0):

License files exist for that very reason. [Here's the link to bootstrap's license.](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/LICENSE)